# The initialization of the CRM authentication pipeline execution has failed for org Org Name with a sql error:

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2013

Hi I am getting the following error in my CRM app server, something went wrong on the SQL server.

error message below;

> The initialization of the CRM authentication pipline execution has failed for org crm-mbtgroup.tarsus.co.za with a sql error: Server: TJHBCRMSQL01, Exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'TraversedPath'.
>   Invalid column name 'PositionId'.

any Idea how I can fix this error. My server doesn't browse, throwing a 404 error. This is CRM version 2013. everything worked fine before and nothing changed out of the ordinary

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by restarting both the application ad SQL box, I would like to know however what caused that issue, anyone with the answer please answer, for now I will mark it complete as that is what fixed the issue for me.